# CMD DIR filename and path

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

I perform a search in the CMD shell.

The goal is to find all files with an x from DRIVE C. I only need to see the path and the filename.

I have tried this so far. If I insert the following, I only get a path.

```
DIR "C:\*x*.*" /s /b
```

How can I also return the filename?

Comment: give it another `/a-d` to exclude folders and show files only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Where` command too:

```dos
Where/R C:\ *x*
```

You can add an `/F` too which places all output files into double quotes.

```dos
Where/F /R C:\ *x*
```

Drives require terminating with a back slash as above directories do not.

```dos
Where/F /R C:\Users\belsober *x*
```

*Note: I've maintained the search mask you used, just remember that this will also match every single file extension too, e.g. `.xml`, `.xls`, `.txt`, `.ocx`, `.exe` and `.docx`*